# How to add vector KML data in an excel table

Tags: vector, cartography

How do I take a KML (or XML) vector map saved on my desktop showing for example a election ward and then import it into excel as a data input in a field of data.

I have information in excel for Geographical boundaries, but I don't have the data in excel to place next to each field to enable the excel to know how to geocache the data to fill a ward something like this?

[image]

Comment: I was not aware that any version of Excel had GIS-like capabilities. In particular, I am puzzled by your references to "geographical boundaries," "geocaching," and "data input in a field of data."  Could you elaborate on what these mean in a spreadsheet environment?  What do you mean by "place next to each field"--are you talking about labeling a map?  Exactly what would be the visible result of "filling a ward"--would it be coloring a map, labeling it, matching data to a polygon identifier, or something else?

Comment: Excel 2013 has PowerMap capabilities (as a plugin) this came from the now discontinued MS MapPoint application http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/powerBI/power-map.aspx